# How i can calcul bandwith by uisng pcap4j

Tags: java, networking, pcap, jnetpcap, pcap4j

I am having issues with the pcap4j library. I want to calculate the bandwidth using a pcap file and I have tried many codes but I have not been successful. One of the codes I have used is:

```
import org.pcap4j.core.PcapHandle;

import org.pcap4j.packet.Packet;

public class PcapBandwidthCalculator {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        String pcapFile = "/path/to/your/pcap/file.pcap";

        PcapHandle handle = PcapHandle.openOffline(pcapFile);

        Packet prevPacket = null;

        long prevTimestamp = 0;

        double totalBandwidth = 0;

        int numPackets = 0;

        while (true) {

            try {

                Packet packet = handle.getNextPacketEx();

                if (prevPacket != null) {

                    long timestamp = packet.getTimestamp().getTime();

                    long duration = timestamp - prevTimestamp;

                    int length = packet.length();

                    double bandwidth = ((double) length) / duration;

                    totalBandwidth += bandwidth;

                    numPackets++;

                }

                prevPacket = packet;

                prevTimestamp = packet.getTimestamp().getTime();

            } catch (Exception e) {

                break;

            }

        }

        double averageBandwidth = totalBandwidth / numPackets;

        System.out.println("Average bandwidth: " + averageBandwidth + " bytes/s");

        handle.close();

    }

}
```

However, I have encountered an issue with the getTimestamp() function as it does not exist in the pcap4j library.